# How to add multiple peers to RTCPeerConnection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, webrtc

I have successfully create a 2 peers chat based on [firebase-rtc-codelab](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/firebase-rtc-codelab) and [FirebaseRTC](https://github.com/webrtc/FirebaseRTC/tree/solution) where 1st peer creates a room id which 2nd peer joins room with.

When 3rd peer joins with the same room id, 1st peer can receive this answer from 3rd peer but connection fails with an error

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Cannot set remote answer in state stable` at

```
 const rtcSessionDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(data.answer);

 await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(rtcSessionDescription);
```

I tried to create a `new peerConnection` every time a new answer is received but it didn't work.

How can the 3rd peer connect successfully?

Can multiple `rtcSessionDescription` be added to `peerConnection` using `setRemoteDescription()` function?

Comment: *One* RTCPeerConnection is between exactly two peers. To create connections between three peers, you need to create additional RTCPeerConnections; each peer needs two RTCPeerConnections to each of their two peers.

Comment: Okay, what if I have a 4th peer? I am trying to achieve a video conference sample where multiple peers can join using same room id, same way multiple people can join a google meet using same link

Answer (score 2):

*One* RTCPeerConnection is between exactly two peers. To create connections between three peers, you need to create additional RTCPeerConnections; each peer needs two RTCPeerConnections to each of their two peers.

> Okay, what if I have a 4th peer?

Then you need to create an additional connection per peer to a third peer each. Yes, each peer must have *(n - 1)* connections, so the total number of connections in your room rises exponentially with each new user joining. This also means each peer has additional up- and download bandwidth requirements with each new peer.

That's why a pure P2P model makes little sense beyond about 3 or 4 users, and you'd rather use an SFU/media server through which media is streamed centrally.

You can also create alternative networks, where peers relay video streams of other peers to each other, but that's not usually where you'd go unless you're in some specific niche situation.

Comment: I have reviewed some blogs about Selective Forwarding Unit(SFU) like [this](https://bloggeek.me/webrtcglossary/sfu/) and [this](https://trueconf.com/blog/wiki/sfu) and SFU seems to be an alternative to P2P. Can you please recommend some tutorials/samples that implement video conferencing using SFU?

Comment: In fact, I cannot. If you're doing this for a small scale project, you may be able to set up your own media server. But if you want to do this at any serious scale, just managing and scaling a media server on your own is a significant enough headache that I'd always recommend using some commercial "video call" service, which comes with its own SDK and abstracts all these headaches away.